# Equivalent to Lua load, setfenv and getfenv in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lua, roblox

I've been testing some stuff out with Lua. I've found some really useful functions (`setfenv`, `getfenv` and `load`). I was wondering if any of these were possible in Javascript as that would be ***super cool***. Note that with the `load` function I mean with all of it's arguments (4 arguments) which `eval` doesn't have. I've tried searching this up but with no luck so I'd be happy if I could get an answer over here. To be even more specific, I'm mainly looking for the 1st and 4th argument of the `load` function.

For those who don't know what `setfenv` or `getfenv` is:
*setfenv*: `setfenv` basically sets the environment for a function. I could basically dynamically add variables from a seperate function.
*getfenv*: `getfenv`, similar to `setfenv` but instead of setting the environment it gets it. I could easily access any variables inside of a function using it.

Thanks, Battledoosh.

Comment: Why do you expect other languages to be as cool as Lua? :-)

Comment: I expect Javascript to be the coolest ✌

Comment: `setfenv` and `getfenv` are Roblox functions, they are not part of Lua's standard functions as your post would suggest.

Comment: No, `setfenv` and `getfenv` are not Roblox functions. They were in Lua 5.1 until they were removed from Lua 5.2+

Comment: It is a Lua standard function.